# WiX Check if file exists

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I cant get this search to work. What is wrong here?

```
<Property Id="HASCONFIGFILE">
    <DirectorySearch Id="ConfigFile" Path="C:\ProgramData\Custom">
      <FileSearch Id="ConfigFileSearch" Name="Config.xml" />
    </DirectorySearch>
  </Property>
```

and here is my condition:

```
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ConfigPageTwo" Order="4"><![CDATA[NOT HASCONFIGFILE]]></Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ConfigPage" Order="5">1</Publish>
```

I get everytime to "ConfigPage" even if I remove the "NOT".

Edit:
Even with "`NOT HASCONFIGFILE OR HASCONFIGFILE`" it is still false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secound publish that comes after needs a condition that is the opposite as the other. Currently it is always true and overwrites the first one.